# curl_exec() expects parameter 1, sting is given

Tags: php, curl

I was using file_get_content like this earlier
`if($html = @DOMDocument::loadHTML(file_get_contents($url))) {.. }`

but switching to curl as it's more secure, but I got error

```
curl_exec() expects parameter 1, sting is given
```

My code

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $html = curl_exec($url);
    curl_close($ch);

      if($html) {

          $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
..
..

}
```

Comment: Any chance you could post the ***real*** error instead of reinterpreting it for us?

Comment: Pretty sure you want `$html = curl_exec($ch);` instead. Have a look through the PHP Curl docs, they are helpful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing the URL string instead of the curl handle

```
 $html = curl_exec($url);
```

change to

```
 $html = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I fixed that but I'm seeing  Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument,

Comment: @ivyong: You *do* realize that cURL only replaces the call to `file_get_contents()`, right?

Comment: Like @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said, cURL does not replace `DOMDocument::loadHTML`. You would need to pass the result from `curl_exec` into the `loadHTML` function still. [More info](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that you are giving string to `curl_exec` , give it the curl handle. Use the code below

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

      if($html) {

          $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
..
..

}
```

Hope this helps you